# Python - Count search words in a text file -- Problem with print(dummy.read())

Tags: python

I am pretty new to the toppic of coding so I hope my question is not too stupid.

Currently I am really at the beginning and try to solve some small excercises to get used the the syntax.
My goal today was a little programm that searches for a search word in a text file.

The program should become bigger therefore I try to du as much as possible in functions.
So I have a function to handle the dummy text (there will be a second function that should handle manual input) and one function that ist just for counting the words in a text.

My problem evolves around line 3 that I commented out. I have the function which opens the text file and then I want to print the text in the console before I asked for the search word. If I dont print it, the program runs normal. When I comment in Line 3 and print the text, the result of hits is always 0.

Maybe you can help me to understand why that happens, what I have to learn and how I can work around it.

```
def dummytext():
    with open("dummy.txt","r",encoding="utf8") as dummy_text:
#       print(dummy_text.read())
        search_word=input("Which word to search for: ")
        return count_words(dummy_text.read(), search_word)

def count_words(search_text, search_word):
    search_count =search_text.count(search_word)
    return search_word, search_count



result = dummytext()
print("The word " + str(result[0])+ " appears "+str(result[1])+" times in the dummy text")
```

Comment: After calling `.read()` on the file once, the current file position is at the very end; calling `.read()` a second time will return nothing (unless more data had been added to the file).  If you want to read the entire file more than once, you either need to close and reopen it, or call `.seek(0)` on the file to rewind to the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were actually very close....

You need to set a variable to get the contents of the read. And then do the search from there.

so, this works:

```
def dummytext():
    with open("F:/code/some_text.txt","r",encoding="utf8") as dummy_text:
        x = dummy_text.read()
        print(x)

        search_word=input("Which word to search for: ")
        return count_words(x, search_word)

def count_words(search_text, search_word):
    search_count =search_text.count(search_word)
    return search_word, search_count



result = dummytext()
print("The word " + str(result[0])+ " appears "+str(result[1])+" times in the dummy text")
```

Also note the comment, which relates to `read()` and `seek()` which is how file reading works.